# node js promises debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, promise

Since last time, node.js just close process with non zero code if unhandled promise rejection have occurred. It is impossible to debug code at all. Even if add uncaught exceptions handler, you will not see errors in place they have occur.

Is it any way to enforce node to stop on errors when debugger is connected?

Otherwise node developing with the promises turn in to the hell much more then it was with callbacks.

Comment: How are you debugging it? If you're using VS Code, there is an option to breakpoint for every (uncaught) exception, which iirc also counts rejecting promises with or without an actual error.

Comment: I tried vscode and i tried crome-devtool, bot of them with "break on caught" and "break on uncaught excptions" enabled. Nothing could make exteptions in promises to break debugging.

Comment: Huh that's weird. I never had the problem of uncaught promises exiting the process, with or without an uncaught exceptions handler or debugger attached. Are you sure there isn't some part of your code that's calling `process.exit`?

Comment: Starting in Node v15, the default behavior is that uncaught promise rejections cause the process to exit. I don't know the answer to the question but one thing that might help is going back to the old behavior while debugging, by running node with `--unhandled-rejections=warn`